# Cannot emulate Android ARM64 on AMD64 Linux

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, arm, x86-64

I installed android studio, and the image for ARM Android 12 (Api level 31), after creating a device in AVD and trying to run the device with the command

```
./emulator @Pixel_5_API_31_ARM
```

I get the output

```
PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host.
```

How do I fix this, since the emulator should run fine

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download and use the x86 image for the emulator. `@Pixel_5_API_31_ARM` indicates a Pixel 5, using Api level 31, on an ARM host. Download and use the appropriate image and you will be fine.